# Breadcrumb in magento

Tags: magento

I am to magento. I got breadcrumb in my static blocks by default. But In my dashboard page, it is not displaying.I have searched in Google but nothing works. Can anyone tell me how to add breadcrumb in my dashboard page.I want to display breadcrumb without using page.xml

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default in magento breadcrumb not come for member account section. You can add breadcrumb using xml. Here is the blog post that explain complete steps:

http://www.douglasradburn.co.uk/adding-breadcrumbs-to-customer-account-pages-in-magento/

You can also use the below extension to add breadcrumb links:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-account-breadcrumbs.html

You need to check its compatibility with latest version.

Comment: and you don't want to add that using xml ?

Comment: I got it by using xml but i dont to give link to home in <link> tag

Comment: like this  <reference name="breadcrumbs">
                <action method="addCrumb">
                        <name>home</name>
                        <params><label>Home</label><title>Home</title><link>/</link></params>
                </action>
                <action method="addCrumb">
                        <name>authors</name>
                        <params><label>Authors</label><title>Authors</title><link>/index.php/managingusers/index/authorlist</link></params>
                </action>
          </reference>

Comment: If you don't want link on home page link you can remove <link> tag from there

Answer (score 2):

```
Go to app\design\frontend\your-package\ your -theme\template\your-modulename\phtml-file and add the following code snippet as per your requirement

// to get breadcrumbs block

<?php $breadcrumbs = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs');
// add first item ‘'home'’ with link

$breadcrumbs->addCrumb(
'home',
 array(
'label'=>$this->__('Home'),
'title'=>$this->__('Home'), 
'link'=>Mage::getBaseUrl()
)
);

// add second item ‘'brands'’ without link

$breadcrumbs->addCrumb(
'brands',
 array(
'label'=>$this->__('Brands'),
'title'=>$this->__('Brands')
)
);

echo $breadcrumbs->toHtml(); ?>
```